# Two way communication using satellite with Android mobile

Tags: android, text, chat, satellite

I am going to make an app which will be communicating with satellite to have two way text communication using Android device. 
How to proceed with this? I have satellite modem and everything else that I might need. Just need a little guidance in regards to this matter.

Comment: what satellites you're talking about?

Comment: @evilone this is getting interesting, +1 to see how it will end

Comment: see guys in that i have satellite modem and that modem is connected with satellite and first i need to connect with android mobile and when connection is established than need to do commnication through satellite with another android device for sending and receiving text message along with location how to do this i need some suggestion

Comment: What is the Satellite network you are planning to use? i.e Inmarsat, Iridium, Thuraya or something else? And secondly, what is the modem you are using? The solution depends on these factors...

Answer (score -1):

I think you just need to handle your normal android programming since your communications is already handled .